# For-loop inside filter method doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, ag-grid

I am using `filter` method to filter out an array as follows:

```
this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(
    this.arrayToFilter.filter(obj => obj.status !== "Declined")
);
```

The above code works fine, but when I try to loop through all the column fields of a table it doesn't work, here is my code:

```
this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.arrayToFilter.filter(function(item) {
    for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        var temp = columns[i].headerName
        if(item[temp] === 'Declined')
            return false
        return true
    }
}));
```

What am I doing wrong in the loop?

Comment: where are the curly braces of if condition?

Comment: @M.HassanNasir it has only one line, so it doesn't need curly braces

Comment: Does it return an error? Or just a wrong filtered values? Can you show your result?

Comment: @RyanGarde it doesn't return any error, the whole table values are shown as normal, wrong filteration

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? In your first code you are comparing the column name 'status' which is good but in second code you are comparing all your headers to 'Declined' which is confusing to me since there are headers like Name or Age (I dont know what exactly are your headers, Im just guessing). You comparing other headers except for status doesnt make sense

Comment: Please add some minimal sample data for `arrayToFilter` and `columns` and the expected output from `filter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logic mistake in your code: Once the headerName of the first column is not 'Declined', it will always return true.

Put `return true` block outside the loop.

```
this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.arrayToFilter.filter(function(item) {
    for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        var temp = columns[i].headerName
        if(item[temp] === 'Declined')
            return false
    }
    return true
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead use map to iterate

```
this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.arrayToFilter.filter(function(item) {
    let checkDeclined = true;
    columns.map(column => {
        let temp = columns[i].headerName
        if(item[temp] === 'Declined')
            checkDeclined = false
        else
            checkDeclined = true
    })
    return checkDeclined;
}));
```

Comment: Will try the solution now,

Comment: This code will never return `checkDeclined = false`

Comment: @adiga why? what is wrong in the code above?

Comment: @mazin it is setting `checkDeclined = true` no matter the condition

Comment: @adiga oh yea, I put it inside if-else

Comment: If you change it to if-else, it will be decided only based on the last element in the array.